# Finding the minium value in an array

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16

Note that I was told this is not the right place to post this kind of question, so please don't waste your time going on to read it. Also, I've to say that at the time, I didn't properly know what stackoverflow.com was for and moreover, I had no idea others stackexchange.com websites existed.

In regard to that, please reconsider the vote you gave to this question (I would delete it but I can't). Thank you.

====================

So, this is one of my first assembly code, what do you think about it?

Specifically

1 Is there a better way I can go thourgh array?

2 I'm using SI to store the array address because I've seen it's a common paradigm to do that. But why to bother? Can't I just use 'VECTOR' instead?

3 Other general advice? (It's my really first code...)

```
.org     100h

.MODEL      SMALL
.DATA
    VECTOR      DW  3,4,2,0,54,-2,3,4
    MIN         DW  ?

.CODE 
.STARTUP
    XOR         AX,AX           ;counter
    LEA         SI,VECTOR       ;store vector address in SI
    MOV         BX,[SI]         ;BX is the minium, let's suppose it's the first element here
    ADD         SI,2            ;I want to go through the array 2byte at once
    INC         AX              ;scanned elements in AX

TESTMIN:
    CMP         BX,[SI]
    JL          GOAHEAD
    MOV         BX,[SI] 

GOAHEAD:    
    ADD         SI,2
    INC         AX
    CMP         AX,8
    JL          TESTMIN            

ret
```

Thank you guys :)

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the place for feedback on working code.

Comment: @RaymondChen thank you, and sorry guys, I won't repeat the error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1 Is there a better way I can go thourgh array?

"Better" depends on what your goal is. If you wanted to minimize the code size you could for example..

- Fuse `MOV BX,[SI]` and `ADD SI,2` into [LODSW](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/spr2002/books/labmanual/inst-ref-lodsb.html) (note that this will give you the loaded word in `AX` instead of `BX`).
- Start the loop counter at 8 and count downwards. This allows you to get rid of the `CMP` at the end and simply use `DEC` / `JNZ`. Or better yet, use `CX` as the loop counter and use the `LOOP` instruction (which decrements `CX` for you).

---

> I'm using SI to store the array address because I've seen it's a common paradigm to do that. But why to bother? Can't I just use 'VECTOR' instead?

Having the address of the array in a register leads to more compact code than putting it as a displacement in every instruction where you want to reference the array, given that you want to reference it at multiple places in your program.